# Как сделать код проще

Tags: php

Есть текстовый файлик

```
jacket.jpg;Куртка;1000;Верхняя одежда
Windbreaker.jpg;Ветровка;1002;Верхняя одежда
Sneakers.jpg;Кросовки;1010;Обувь
boots.jpg;Ботинки;1005;Обувь
pants.jpg;Штаны;1008;Одежда
shirt.jpg;Рубашка;1004;Одежда
Cap.jpg;Кепка;1007;Головные уборы
```

я его преобразую в таблицу

```
<?php
$file1 = fopen("category.txt", "r");
$files = array($file1);
   foreach($files as $file){
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    $value[]= explode(';',trim($line));
  }
}
echo'<table>';
$row=count($value);
$set=$row/'3'; 
for ($tr1=0; $tr1<$set; $tr1++){
echo'<tr>';
for ($tr=0; $tr<=2; $tr++){
$s='<td><img width="64px" src="C:\image\\'.$value[$tr1*3+$tr][0].'"><br>Название:'.$value[$tr1*3+$tr][1].'<br>цена:'.$value[$tr1*3+$tr][2].'</td>';
echo $s;
}
echo'</tr>';
}
echo'</table>';
?>
```

Получается 2 окошка в третей строке таблицы с ошибками. https://ibb.co/vZG9VQq

Comment: Использовать табуляции хотя бы.

Comment: Проще в том плане чтобы костыль не делать вида "$tr1*3+$tr", а там через break; допустим пока хочу в таблице в строке выводить по 3 элемента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

давайте напишем по другому: можно воспользоваться [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php), а можно сразу получить массив строк при помощи [file](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php). И побить на группы по три при помощи [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php)

```
$values = array_map(function ($line) { return explode(';',trim($line));},
               file("category.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES |FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
$values = array_chunk($values, 3);

echo '<table>';
foreach($values as $row) {
    echo'<tr>';
    foreach($row as $item) {
        echo '<td><img width="64px" src="C:\image\\'.$item[0].'"><br>Название:'.$item[1].'<br>цена:'.$item[2].'</td>';
    }
    echo'</tr>';
}

echo'</table>';
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'  line 3

Comment: Скобку не закрыл. Хорошо, что сказали, а то осталась бы ошибка потомкам :)

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in  line 10 цвета выводит а название и цену пустые  https://ibb.co/pnFwmXb

Comment: сейчас пробуйте